# How to call exists() without quotation marks

Tags: r

I am trying to use `exists()` to check whether a variable has been assigned in my R session. However, it confuses me that you have to use quotation marks... e.g.

```
> exists("con_psql")
[1] TRUE
> exists(con_psql)
Error in exists(con_psql) : invalid first argument
```

As an aside, it is not clear to me what happens if you apply `exists` to a variable, e.g.:

```
> temp_file_list = ls()
> exists(temp_file_list)
[1] TRUE
```

But:

```
> temp_file_list[[length(temp_file_list) +1 ]] = "bogus_variable_name"
> exists(temp_file_list)
[1] TRUE
```

and:

```
> temp_file_list = list("bogus_variable_name",temp_file_list)
> temp_file_list = unlist(temp_file_list)
> exists(temp_file_list)
[1] FALSE
```

Does this mean `exists()` only checks the first entry in the list? If so, I find this particular aspect not terribly useful.

I much rather be able to check the existence of a single variable in the workspace without quotes, which also seems to be more logical to me.

Comment: a possible hacky solution would be to use stackoverflow.com/questions/5011348/how-can-i-eliminate-quote-marks-around-parameters-in-r-function/5011396#5011396 and rewrite the exists function using this answer.

Comment: `exists` only accepts "a variable name (given as a character string)" unlike `mget` which accepts " a character vector of object names.". So yes, it only looks at the first character variable. But why are you writing code that is unsure if particular variables exist in the environment. That doesn't seem like a great strategy.

Comment: You could define `vexists<-function(x) exists(deparse(substitute(x)))` and use `vexists(con_psql)`

Comment: I am callings `exists` for error log purposes, I am trying to retrieve data over a sql connection, so it is possible that the variable might not be stored due to a failure of the connector.

Comment: But what sql connection returns results by attaching an object to the current environment? Don't they usually return an object like a data.frame or a list with names you can check? Do you just need some form of `is.null`?

Comment: I am trying to do `data = dbGetQuery(con_psql, build_sql_query)`, using either RPostgreSQL package (and also RMySQL), where the first variable is the connection and the second is the sql query. I am not 100% sure, but if for example the connection goes away (maybe due to failed ssh tunnel), then no data will actually write to `data`.

Comment: e.g. `data_test = dbGetQuery(con_test,build_sql_query)` when con_test is not a valid connection, followed by `is.null(data_test)` returns `Error: object 'data_test' not found`, but `exists("data_test")` results in `[1] FALSE`.

Comment: if you want to be defensive about those types of errors, then look at `?tryCatch`. That's a better way to grab the error then checking if the assignment finished.

Comment: Thanks, I've started using tryCatch and it is working well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define a function what will deparse the parameter for you and pass it along

```
vexists <- function(...) {
    vars<-as.character(substitute(...()))
    sapply(vars, exists)
})
```

Then you could call

```
vexists(con_psql)
```

or

```
vexists(con_psql, bogus_variable_name)
```

or any number of arguments

Comment: This is exactly what I would recommend -- it's the approach taken in the code for `library` .